# Julia metaprogramming with using/imports

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

I would like to evaluate an expression that imports a Module, based on an argument `expr`. So far, I came up with:

```
julia> expr = :(Base.Threads)

julia> @eval using $expr
ERROR: TypeError: import or using: expected Symbol, got Expr
Stacktrace:
 [1] eval(::Module, ::Expr) at ./sysimg.jl:23
```

One possibility is to use `Expr` constructor directly, like this:

```
julia> expr = [:Base, :Threads]
2-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :Base   
 :Threads

julia> eval(Expr(:using, expr...))
```

But is there any other, perhaps more straightforward way without the need of constructing `Expr`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each space delimited character group after the macro name is considered to be a separate argument. Instead,  you should just write the expression in between parentheses.

```
@eval(using $expr)
```